# Repeating Python script with output from previous step

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5

I have a raster with gaps in it and want to fill the gaps with the mean of the surrounding cells using focal statistics. I found the code to achieve this here 
[Fill in NoData gaps in raster using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136075/fill-in-nodata-gaps-in-raster-using-arcgis-for-desktop)

I then want to take the output from the focal statistics and repeat about 15 times in order to expand the raster.

I have managed to get it to work somewhat but it stops after about 3 iterations

```
arcpy.env.workspace= r'C:\Users\Environmental\Tides\Analysis\Analysis.gdb'

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 

Waves = arcpy.sa.Con(arcpy.sa.IsNull("M2_reproj.tif"),arcpy.sa.FocalStatistics("M2_reproj.tif",arcpy.sa.NbrCircle(1),'MEAN'), "M2_reproj.tif")
Waves.save("C:\Users\Environmental\Tides\Analysis\Waves.tif")

seq = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

for num in seq:
    Waves = arcpy.sa.Con(arcpy.sa.IsNull("Waves"),arcpy.sa.FocalStatistics("Waves",arcpy.sa.NbrCircle(1),'MEAN'), "Waves") 
    Waves.save("C:\Users\jtwh3\TOM_GIS\Environmental\Tides\Analysis\Waves.tif")
```

Comment: do you get an error when the code stops or does it say it was executed successfully?

Comment: there is no error, it seems to execute correctly but the raster has only expanded by 3 cells

Comment: How are you running this?You set the work space to a geodatabase but then you reference tiff files

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I'm running this in the python window

Comment: In relation to setting the workspace, if I don't set the workspace to a geodatabase for some reason the code doesn't work properly? I then save the files as tiffs as if i don't i get an error that the file  can't be found