# Interpolate for no data areas in a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, interpolation, focal-statistics

I have a raster of the average chlorophyll-a concentration for 1 year (NASA MODIS LEVEL2 1km res). However i am still missing values for the pixels near the coastal zone (really important for our study). 
Is there anyway I can interpolate and fill these fairly accurately?

So far i have just been experimenting with focal statistics in arcgis, but not really getting accurate results....

[image: snip of part of study area]

Answer (score 1):

I would say using focal statistics is actually the right approach. What is the problem with the results by using focal statistics?

This thread should help you: [Fill in NoData gaps in raster using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136075/fill-in-nodata-gaps-in-raster-using-arcgis-for-desktop)