# Seeking"Fill nodata" tool in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, interpolation

I have some NoData cells in my grid (landuse) which I want to fill depending on the neighbouring cells - more precisely the edges. In QGIS there is a [tool](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_analysis/fillnodata.html) from GDAL that does exactly that.

Is there an equivalent tool in ArcMap?

I have not found anything similar so far.

Comment: Does this work for you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136075/filling-nodata-gaps-in-raster-using-arcgis-desktop

Answer (score 0):

I found an useful tool: [shrink](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/shrink.htm).
It "shrinks the selected zones by a specified number of cells by replacing them with the value of the cell that is most frequent in its neighborhood".